# Electron Desktop App: Using mysql data in a component with Angular2 front end

Tags: mysql, node.js, angular, electron

I'm new to Electron and is my first attempt at creating an app.
This is a desktop app.
One page of the app is just displaying a current forecast by customer with standard database queries.

I'm using a local DB (mysql) to hold summary data such as sales, forecasts, by period. I've successfully pulled the information from the database in a javascript file using the mysql module.

```
**var mysql = require('mysql')
//credentials for the database
var connection = mysql.createConnection({
    host        :'localhost',
    user        :'root',
    password    :'root',
    database    :'dw' 
});
...etc**
```

I'm wanting to use Angular2 on the front-end which uses TypeScript.
How do I send the information that I get pull from the Database (Javascript) into the Angular Component which is in Typescript and are in different files ?

Is this performed via IPC between the rendered and the main page ?
HTTP services calls to the DB seem like overkill since it's on the same pc.
Do I need to just require the Javascript DB calls into the component ?

Comment: Have you found the way to do this? So far I was only able to use connect to the DB via main.js and communicate between Angular's components and the main thread via `ipcMain/ipcRenderer` messages. Would love to know if there's a better solution.

Answer (score 4):

**UPDATE**
It IS possible to call the db directly from components without communicating with the main thread.
Create a `DB` service:

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
const mysql = (<any>window).require('mysql');

@Injectable()
export class DBService {
    connection: any;

    constructor() {
        this.connection = mysql.createConnection({
            host: 'localhost',
            user: 'username',
            password: 'password',
            database: 'db_name'
        });
        this.connection.connect((err) => {
           if (err) {
             console.log('error connecting', err);
           }
        });
    }

    query(sql: string) {
        this.connection.query(sql, function(err, results, fields) {
            console.log('err', err);
            console.log('results', results);
            console.log('fields', fields);
        });
    }
}
```

Then, within any of your Angular 2+ components:

```
import {Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {DBService} from './services/db.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(private db: DBService) {}
  ngOnInit() {}
  getProducts() {
      this.db.query('SELECT * FROM product');
  }
}
```

**Old Answer**

This is my current workaround to connect to mysql with Angular 2+.

On `main.js`:

```
const {app, BrowserWindow, ipcMain} = require('electron')

const mysql = require('mysql')
const connection = mysql.createConnection({
    host     : 'localhost',
    user     : 'username',
    password : 'password',
    database: 'your_database'
});
connection.connect(function(err) {
    if (err) {
        console.log('connect', err);
    }
});

ipcMain.on('query', function(e, sql) {
    console.log('query received', sql);
    connection.query(sql, function(err, rows, fields) {
        if(err){
            console.log('error executing', err);
            return false;
        }
        console.log('success', rows);
    });
});
```

create a `DB` Service (app/services/db.service.ts)

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
const electron = (<any>window).require('electron');

@Injectable()
export class DBService {

  constructor() { }

  query(sql: string) {
      electron.ipcRenderer.send('query', sql);
  }
}
```

(don't forget to add to it to `app.modules.ts`)

```
import {DBService} from './services/db.service';
...
providers: [DBService]
```

Then in any component in your Angular2+ app you can use it:

```
        import {DBService} from './services/db.service';
        ...
        constructor(private db: DBService) {}
        getProducts() {
           this.db.query('SELECT * FROM product');
        }
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

You don't necessarily need to write the MySQL client code in javascript. You can use the type declarations: https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/mysql

If you really want to use javascript, then you will need a minimal set of type declarations to be written. Just enough to make the typescript compiler believe that the functions you use do exist. No need for any IPC, after the typescript code gets compiled, at run-time it will just end up in a javascript function calling an other javascript functions.

The key point is that you have to make the typescript compiler believe that the MySQL library exists. To achieve it, you either install the typings from the package linked above, or write a minimal declaration yourself.

Comment: Thanks ! I will use the npm package as you suggested and skip the javascript.